# React Hook Form and Antd: how to change the sent value of my multiple Antd Select

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-hook-form

I'm working in a React app with Antd and React Hook Form, I want to edit te sent value of my React-Hook-Form, I'm using Controller, This is my code:

```js
<Controller
        control={control}
        rules={{ required }}
        name={field}
        render={({ field }) => (
            <Select
                mode='multiple'
                allowClear
                {...field}
            >
                {items.length > 0
                ? items.map((item) => (
                <Option
                key={item.id}
                value={JSON.stringify(item.id)}
            >
            {item.label}
            </Option>
            ))
            : null}
            </Select>
            )}
        />
```

The Value of my Select field is ['1474','7458','4569']

The expected value : '1474;7458;4569'

I Want to have a string with all Ids separated with commas instead of getting an array of the Ids

I did'nt found anythings in the API on Antd, have you any ideas please ?
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a codesandbox link of your current code if possible. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71524345/react-hook-form-how-to-customize-controllers-sent-value