# React Hook Form : how to customize Controller's sent value

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-hook-form

I'm using React and Antd with React-Hook-Form (Controller) and I'm looking for a solution to customize my Controller response when I click on submit button :

With Antd : the multiple select mode sent an array with all selected value, I want to send a string with all selected values separated by commas :

Example :

My actual Output : ['A','B','C','D']

Expected output : 'A;B;C;D'

I want to convert my array to string with (;) , [This my my actual Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-js-forked-8m2wiv?file=/src/App.js).

Have you any idea how to achieve that please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by doing this:

`onChange={(e) => field.onChange(console.log(e.join(";")))}`

you can do the same to `handleSubmit` by changing it to

`onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data.fields.join(';')))}`

Comment: Hi! but when I add another Input Controller the handleSubmit not handling all fields in your example.. Can you clarify please ? :) thanks

Comment: @Tania12 because as far as I can see, `onChange` should be assigned to the `onChange` prop of `({field})` and since it's already passed in `{...field}` it makes the data `undefined`, see this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-js-forked-c5wv2i)